# ¿Como hago un hover a un jLabel?

Tags: java, java-swing

Quiero hacer un hover en un jLabel para que cuando pase el mouse por arriba cambie de color las letras, tengo este codigo:

[image: Codigo usado para el hover del jLabel]

Creo que deberia andar, no tengo ningun otro lugar que cambie el foreground color ni el background color ni nada referido a los jLabel. Pero cuando paso el mouse la primera vez por encima del jLabel pasa esto:

[image: Parte de un jMenuBar en el fondo del jLabel]

No se ve mucho pero en el fondo se ve una parte de un jMenuBar que tengo o.0. Intente hacer lo mismo con Underline al jLabel y paso esto:

[image: Casi todo el jMenuBar en el fondo del jLabel]

Y cuando saco el mouse y lo vuelvo a pasar muchas veces por arriba del jLabel pasa esto:

[image: Esto pasa al pasar el mouse muchas veces encima del jLabel]

Se pone asi en negro y queda ahi. Asumo que lo negro seria el background asique intente poner un setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0)); osea con opacidad 0. pero no cambia nada. Agradezco de antemano.

Comment: Los JLabel, por defecto, son transparentes. Así que setBackground() no suele tener ningún efecto y setForeground() solo afecta al texto. Si quieres cambiar el background de un JLabel, debes llamar primero a setOpaque(true).

No sé cómo tienes montado los layout y los componentes, pero el problema de que el JLabel aparezca encima del JMenu parece más tema de colocación de componentes que de colores. Como el JLabel es transparente, se verá lo que hay debajo, el JMenu en tu caso. Más que colores de JLabel, revisa la colocación de los componentes y por qué el JLabel está encima del JMenuBar